# Contact form swift 4 without using default mail.

Tags: ios, swift4

So I made a contact form in my app, it has it’s own ViewController. I have 3 text fields and 1 send button. I have it working good but i could only find tutorials to have it just open up the default mail composer with the message area filled with the info from the textfields. My question is, is there a way I could not use the default mail composer and have it just send and close that ViewController?

Comment: You will need to use a service, like [MailGun](https://www.mailgun.com)

Comment: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-objc try this

Comment: I got MailGun but can’t find any tutorials on how to implement it in my app on Swift 4.

Comment: Any help is appreciated.